# Deleting zeros from string column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column in my dataframe,where the values are something like this:

```
col1:
    00000000000012VG
    00000000000014SG
    00000000000014VG
    00000000000010SG
    20000000000933LG
    20000000000951LG
    20000000000957LG
    20000000000963LG
    20000000000909LG
    20000000000992LG
```

I want to delete all zeros:

a)that are in front of other numbers and letters(For example in case of `00000000000010SG` I want to delete this part`000000000000` and keep `10SG`).

b) In cases like `20000000000992LG` I want to delete this part `0000000000` and unite `2` with `992LG`.

str.stprip('0') solves only part a), as I checked.

But what is the right solution for both cases?

Comment: Sorry, in `20000000000963LG` need `963LG` or `2963LG` ?

Comment: OP, please note the correction in my post: `df.col1.str.replace(r'[0]{2,}', '', 1)` to replace just the _first_ instance ONLY.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend something similar to Ed's answer, but using regex to ensure that not *all* 0s are replaced, and the eliminate the need to hardcode the number of 0s.

```
In [2426]: df.col1.str.replace(r'[0]{2,}', '', 1)
Out[2426]: 
0      12VG
1      14SG
2      14VG
3      10SG
4    2933LG
5    2951LG
6    2957LG
7    2963LG
8    2909LG
9    2992LG
Name: col1, dtype: object
```

Only the first string of 0s is replaced.

Thanks to @jezrael for pointing out a small bug in my answer.

Comment: @jezrael Fixed. It will only replace the first instance now.

Answer (score 2):

You can just do

```
In[9]:
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace('000000000000','')
df['col1'] = df['col1'].str.replace('0000000000','')
df

Out[9]: 
         col1
0        12VG
1        14SG
2        14VG
3        10SG
4      2933LG
5      2951LG
6      2957LG
7      2963LG
8      2909LG
9      2992LG
```

This will replace a fixed number of `0`s with a blank space, this isn't dynamic but for your given dataset this is the simplest thing to do unless you can explains better the pattern